# How to put Linux Boot Manager in front of Windows Boot Manager?

Tags: bios, multi-boot, arch-linux

Edit: I use systemd-boot

I have set up a dual boot with Windows 10 and Arch on my laptop, but I can't move the Linux Boot Manager option from the Boot Option Menu in front of the Windows Boot Manager:

[image]

[image]

I tried putting HDD0 at slot 1 but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have GRUB2:

To customize your GRUB2 settings, you’ll have to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and then run the `sudo update-grub` command.

> Choose the Default OS: Change the GRUB_DEFAULT= line. By default,
>   GRUB_DEFAULT=0 uses the first entry as the default — change the number
>   to 1 to use the second entry, 2 to use the third entry, or so on. You
>   could also use GRUB_DEFAULT=saved and GRUB would automatically boot
>   the last operating system you chose each time you boot. You can also
>   specify a label in quotes. For example, if you had an operating system
>   named Windows 7 (loader) in your OS list, you could use
>   GRUB_DEFAULT=”Windows 7 (loader)”

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use systemd-boot, I edited my question

Comment: Please take a look: http://serverfault.com/questions/482730/systemd-dependencies-and-boot-order

Answer (score 1):

This is not "BIOS", this is not your bootloader's boot menu; this is the **UEFI** boot menu. You can change its order via the "BootOrder" EFI variable; Linux has a command `efibootmgr` for that:

```
# efibootmgr
BootOrder: 0003,0000
Boot0000* Linux Boot Manager
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager

# efibootmgr --bootorder 0000,0003
```

(Bonus feature: `--bootnext` lets you choose an OS just for *one* reboot, so you can make an alias like `windows() { sudo efibootmgr --bootnext 0003 && systemctl reboot; }`.)

Comment: This didn't work, the boot order is reset every restart. I found others have the same problem, it is discribed here: https://github.com/rhinstaller/efibootmgr/issues/19
And this was the "solution": https://communities.intel.com/thread/43629
The boot menus 1st entry is just the name of my HDD0, but it boots Linux so it's okay. And if I want to boot Windows I can select it too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the boot order edited with:

```
efibootmgr --bootorder
```

would be reset every reboot, I found this: https://github.com/rhinstaller/efibootmgr/issues/19

Someone postet their solution there: https://communities.intel.com/thread/43629 
The boot menus 1st entry is just the name of my HDD0 now, but it boots Linux so it's okay. And if I want to boot Windows I can select it too.